# Python remove keys with the same value on a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to do a not "natural" operation on a dictionary so i wondering what is the best pythonic way to do this.

I need to simplify a dictionary by removing all the keys on it with the same value (keys are differents, values are the same)

For example:
Input:

```
  dict = {key1 : [1,2,3], key2: [1,2,6], key3: [1,2,3]}
```

expected output:

```
  {key1 : [1,2,3], key2:[1,2,6]}
```

I dont care about which key is delete (on the example: key1 or key3)

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: But what is the use of doing this. I think you should look if you really need the key-value pair you thought, or it is the reverse. Although there are ways, you can perform what you insisted earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exchange keys and values; duplicated key-value pairs will be removed as a side effect (because dictionary does not allow duplicated keys). Exchange keys and values again.

```
>>> d = {'key1': [1,2,3], 'key2': [1,2,6], 'key3': [1,2,3]}
>>> d2 = {tuple(v): k for k, v in d.items()}  # exchange keys, values
>>> d = {v: list(k) for k, v in d2.items()}   # exchange again
>>> d
{'key2': [1, 2, 6], 'key1': [1, 2, 3]}
```

NOTE: `tuple(v)` was used because `list` is not hashable; cannot be used as key directly.

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It will shadow builtin function/type `dict`.

Comment: Evtl. add a sort to the list/tuple to make sure same values in different order in the lists are treated as the same. +1.

Answer (score 2):

This solution deletes the keys with same values without creating a new dictionary.

```
seen = set()
for key in mydict.keys():
    value = tuple(mydict[key])
    if value in seen:
        del mydict[key]
    else:
        seen.add(value)
```

Comment: 'RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration' @ozgur Any clue ?

Comment: for key in mydict.copy():

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over  your dict items and use a set to check what we have seen so far, deleting a key if we have already seen the value:

```
d = {"key1" : [1,2,3], "key2": [1,2,6], "key3": [1,2,3]}
seen = set()
for k, v in d.items(): # list(items) for python3
    temp = tuple(v) 
    if temp in seen:
        del d[k]
    seen.add(temp)
print(d)
{'key1': [1, 2, 3], 'key2': [1, 2, 6]}
```

This will be more efficient that using creating a dict and reversing the values as you only have to cast to tuple once not from a tuple back to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way also. But I don't say as there seems to be more efficient ways. It is in-line.

```
for i in dictionary.keys():
    if dictionary.values().count(dictionary[i]) > 1:
       del dictionary[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
seen = set()
for key in mydict.copy():
    value = tuple(mydict[key])
    if value in seen:
        del mydict[key]
    else:
        seen.add(value)
```