# Decomposing complex data structure consisting of dictionary and list of tuples to extract common elements

Tags: python

I have found myself in an awkward situation with a complex data structure consisting of dictionary of list of tuples. The thing is multiple keys within the dictionary have common tuple elements, and I want to filter out common elements into categories of non-redundant tuple elements. I hope a sample of the data would provide a gist of the problem.

```
test = {'S37_1': [('L26_1', '100.000'), ('S13_1', '100.000'), ('L29_1', '100.000'), ('S37_1', '100.000'), ('S38_1', '99.910'), ('L25_1', '99.910'), ('L16_1', '99.888')],\
        'L29_1': [('L26_1', '100.000'), ('S13_1', '100.000'), ('L29_1', '100.000'), ('S37_1', '100.000'), ('S38_1', '99.910'), ('L25_1', '99.910'), ('L16_1', '99.888')], \
        'L25_2': [('S38_3', '100.000'), ('L16_4', '100.000'), ('L25_2', '100.000'), ('L29_3', '99.889'), ('L26_2', '99.783'), ('S13_2', '99.777'), ('S37_2', '99.464')], \
        'S38_3': [('S38_3', '100.000'), ('L16_4', '100.000'), ('L25_2', '100.000'), ('L29_3', '99.889'), ('L26_2', '99.783'), ('S13_2', '99.777'), ('S37_2', '99.464')]}
```

The expected result may be as so:

```
test = {'S37_1': [('L26_1', '100.000'), ('S13_1', '100.000'), ('L29_1', '100.000'), ('S37_1', '100.000'), ('S38_1', '99.910'), ('L25_1', '99.910'), ('L16_1', '99.888')],\
        'L25_2': [('S38_3', '100.000'), ('L16_4', '100.000'), ('L25_2', '100.000'), ('L29_3', '99.889'), ('L26_2', '99.783'), ('S13_2', '99.777'), ('S37_2', '99.464')]}
```

The code below makes a set of all non redundant lists of tuples without separating them into categories so I would appreciate for an help on how to modify it in such a way as to filter the "test" dictionary and remove all keys which do not provide new information.

```
seen = set()
keep = []

for elem, tp_elms in test.items():
       for hit, stat in tp_elms:
              if hit in seen:
                     print(hit,stat)
              else:
                     seen.add(hit)
                     keep.append((hit,stat))
```

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you decide which keys to keep? Insertion order, or by sorting? If you don't care which one you keep you can use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395373/python-remove-keys-with-the-same-value-on-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to slightly modify the code in which we loop over all the elements and do not add the entries that have all elements already seen.

```
seen = set()
keep = {}

for elem, tp_elms in test.items():
    if all(tup in seen for tup in tp_elms):
        continue
    keep[elem] = tp_elms
    seen.update(tp_elms)
```